# Ignore second match's HTML if not matched

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm writing a regular expression that should do the following:

```
== Text ==
Other text
==     Text==
```

Becomes

```
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Other text</p>
<h2>Text</h2>
```

I'm almost there, the problem is that this is what I currently get:

```
<h2>Text</h2>
<p>Other text</p>
<h2>Text</h2>
<p></p>
```

Even though it's unlikely the heading will not be followed by text, I want to fix it at least for learning purposes.

Here is my function:

```
preg_replace('/== *(.*?) *==([^=]*)/m', 
             '<h2>$1</h2>
              <p>$2</p>
             ', '== Text ==
                 Other text
                 ==     Text==');
```

So basically, I want to ignore the `<p></p>` part if `$2` is empty.

Any other tips / improvements are welcomed, I want to learn :)

Comment: You should scrap this regex and parse the input line by line. Will prevent you from going crazy later on.

Comment: Because if you later want to add any more options you will not be able to.

Comment: How would I go about this, split up the regular expression to match either `== *(.*?) *==` or not and if it doesn't just add `<p></p>` or something?

Comment: I added a proper answer, check it out.

Comment: in case this is for Markdown or Wiki markup, there is parsers/generators for that, so you dont have to do that by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one simple conditional to prevent the empty `<p>` tag from appearing. While I would not recommend this usually, the easiest way to insert this simple `if` is by using the `/e` regex modifier to [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/== *(.*?) *==([^=]*)/me', 
             '"<h2>$1</h2>".(trim("$2") == ""?"":"<p>$2</p>")',
             '== Text ==
                 Other text
              ==     Text==');
```

This modifier makes the replacement string be evaluated as PHP code before making the replacement, so you can fit a small conditional in there easily.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/s06A6)**.

Another option would be to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), which is effectively the same idea only that you now write the code as a separate function. This is better IMHO because it makes for clearer code.

As a final note, if you intend to add more formatting options you might want to consider breaking your parsing down into multiple steps and possibly processing one line at a time because regular expressions are not designed to handle this kind of processing. You can force it up to a point, but then it starts to become very unmaintainable very quickly.

Comment: That's a nice modifier, I'll certainly be looking into `preg_replace_callback` for the reason you supplied, wouldn't want my PHP code highlighted as a string within a function.

Comment: Another question though, if regular expressions are not designed for this kind of processing, is there a better way? Or do you simply mean I should be careful with how far I go. As far as I know BBCode and variations are used on almost every forum (and this site), and these are written with regular expressions right?

Comment: @Kokos: Right, but they don't try to parse all BBCodes with one regex at the same time. That's what I mean "break parsing down into multiple steps".

Comment: Ah, yeah I wasn't planning on that. I was more wondering about the 'processing one line at a time' bit, since this will always expect people to put their stuff on different lines. You helped me out a great deal and teached me some stuff, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How about doing this in two steps:

First add paragraph markers around each line that doesn't begin/end with `==`:

```
$firststep = preg_replace('/^(?![ \t]*==.*==[ \t]*$).+/m', '<p>\0</p>', $subject);
```

Then add heading markers around each line that does begin/end with `==`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*==[ \t]*(.*?)[ \t]*==[ \t]*$/m', '<h2>\1</h2>', $firststep);
```

Comment: Certainly a good solution, however I can't trust my clients to always put their heading markers on separate lines.